# Cannot setup GDK on MacOS

Tags: ruby, macos, gitlab

Welcome, I’m trying to setup GDK locally to start on Hackathon issues, but seems some packages blocking me.

After arriving to gitlab-development-kit `wpplumber$ gdk install` it gives the error below:

```
    gdk install
The following Brewfile's dependencies are missing or outdated:

- dpkg
- git-lfs
- graphicsmagick

To install these dependencies, run the following command:

  (cd /Users/wpplumber/Workspace/Gitlab/devs/gitlab-development-kit && brew bundle)
make[1]: *** [preflight-checks-run] Error 1
make: *** [preflight-checks-timed] Error 2
❌️ ERROR: Failed to install.
-------------------------------------------------------
You can try the following that may be of assistance:

- Run 'gdk doctor'.

- Visit the troubleshooting documentation:
  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/-/blob/main/doc/troubleshooting/index.md.
- Visit https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/-/issues to
  see if there are known issues.

- Run 'gdk reset-data' if appropriate.
- Run 'gdk pristine' which will restore your GDK to a pristine state.
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried running what it is suggesting you to? What were the outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after long journey and even the hackathon completed I got it installed.

I recommend the following:
Install: `clang, GCC, Postgres, Redis`

> Use only the brew and asdf package managers.